# How to input different classes and put it to the common array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, abstract-class, virtual

I have a task:
Create abstract class Product, then create two inheritant abstract classes MilkProduct and MeatProduct and their inheritants (Milk, Meat, Kefir, Sausage) and output them in descending order by their codes.

```
public abstract class Product {
protected String name;
protected int code;

public Product() {}
public Product(String name, int code) {
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
}

public abstract void input();
public String toString() {
    return "{Name : " + name
            + ";" + "Code: "
            + code + "}";
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
}
}


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Product[] arr = new Product[10];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        arr[i].input();
        if (arr[i].name == "Milk") {
            arr[i] = new Milk(arr[i].name, arr[i].code);
        }
        else if (arr[i].name == "Kolbasa") {
            arr[i] = new Kolbasa(arr[i].name, arr[i].code);
        }
        else if (arr[i].name == "Meat") {
            arr[i] = new Meat(arr[i].name, arr[i].code);
        }
        else if (arr[i].name == "Kefir") {
            arr[i] = new Kefir(arr[i].name, arr[i].code);
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for (Product e: arr) {
        e.toString();
    }
}
}
```

and i got an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   HWvirtual.Program.main(Program.java:11)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: `arr[i].input();` In each iteration you call this because you actually initialize i-th element of an array, it is always null.